# Determine which JavaScript objects were freed by GC

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to find a way, in any desktop browser, to determine which JavaScript-allocated objects are being **freed** by garbage collection. Please note, I am **not** trying to track "leaks." Leaks are objects that did **not** get freed.

In Firefox, the web app I'm looking at occasionally stutters (stops responding to keystrokes for >1 second); profiling reveals that during that time, the browser is performing a lengthy GC. Over the previous several seconds, a significant amount of memory was added (in small chunks, not all at once). When the GC happens, almost all of that memory gets freed.

What I'm trying to figure out is: What *are* all these short-lived objects, anyway? I would love to know their values, their types, or where in the JS they were allocated.

The web app exhibits these same allocation patterns in all browsers (although only Firefox seems to suffer from a lengthy GC); so I would happily use any browser (Mac or Windows) to debug this.

I've figured out how to use Chrome's dev tools to look at **leaked** objects, but as I mention above, leaks are not my concern. I can't figure out a way to see what objects got allocated and then freed.

Answer (score 0):

GC is just the end of the lifecycle. At the beginning there are allocations.

So instead of trying to figure out what gets collected you can use the devtools' allocation recording.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? If you're talking about the "Record Heap Allocations" button, how can I use that to show me all allocations (including those that end up getting GC'd)?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling#object-allocation-tracker

Comment: at least FF dev edition should have allocation stack recording too

Comment: Regarding your link to https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling#object-allocation-tracker , thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't do the trick. As noted in the FAQ: "Q: Are 'dead' (unreachable) objects included in snapshots? A: No. Only reachable objects are included in snapshots. Also, taking a snapshot always starts with doing a GC."